# Como implementar servidor APNS usando EasyAPNS?

Tags: php, ios, web-service, apns, apple-push-notification

Estou tentando usar o EasyAPNS em um projeto para iOS 8. Mas devido ao fato do projeto ser antigo e não haver atualizações para ele, estou tendo problemas.

Mais especificamente, com relação ao servidor, que embora esteja corretamente configurado conforme o video tutorial do Raphael Caixeta, apresenta o seguinte problema no arquivo de log:

> 10-Nov-2014 20:18:03 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Fatal error:  Push Badge
>   must be either Enabled or Disabled.
>
> 1) APNS::__construct -> File: apns.php (line 55)    2)
>   APNS::_registerDevice -> File: class_APNS.php (line 252)  3)
>   APNS::_triggerError -> File: class_APNS.php (line 319)
>
> in /home/pensesof/public_html/apns/classes/class_APNS.php on line 706

Alguém usa, ou está usando o EasyAPNS em projetos atuais?

Comment: Tiago, desenvolvi um em Python, se for útil pra você... fique á vontade: https://github.com/vsouza/Bird

Comment: Obrigado! Vou dar uma olhada sim!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, obrigado pela ajuda!

Eu desisti de usar o EasyAPNS pois estava dando muito problema, e fiz um reutilizando o código fonte do tutorial do site www.raywenderlich.com.

Para quem quiser uma cópia do codigo fonte do tutorial está aqui: http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip

Com base neste arquivo, criei um simples server.